# Changing color space on and image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I'm creating a mask based on DeviceGray color space based image.

What basically I want to do is to change all sorts of gray (beside black) pixels into white and leave black pixels as they are.

So I want my image to be consisted with black and white pixels.

Any idea how to achieve that using CoreGraphics means ?

Please dont offer running all over the pixels in the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors` and `CGContextSetRGBFillColor` together like this:

```
CGImageRef myMaskedImage;
const CGFloat myMaskingColors[6] = { 0, 124, 0, 68, 0, 0 };
myColorMaskedImage = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors (image,
                                        myMaskingColors);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (myContext, 0.6373,0.6373, 0, 1);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, myColorMaskedImage);
```

By the way, the fill color is mentioned at the [CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors) discussion.

Comment: I've applied the code provided here on my picture still i get the gray pixels, I need to keep black pixels and convert all sorts on gray pixels into white.

Comment: @deimus You should change the color range and the fill color in the snippet, did you do that ?

Comment: hah sorry I'm just too noob yet in Quartz :), Just to confirm is following range right to get all gray colors beside black {1, 255, 1, 255, 1, 255}

Comment: That must be correct for RGB, see the formula at the documentation link.

Comment: CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors : what does this actually stands for ?

Comment: @Shailesh Always check  [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/index.html) when you have such questions. Actually the answer already has the link where you could find the same information.