# Changing the particular color in an image

Tags: iphone, ios

By using the following image i want to write code.

[image]

here is the image i want to do this one programmatically.
User can select roof or wall or fencing or windows. After selecting the particular part and color(another model) then the present color(another model) should replace with selected color.

In this image(example) user selected color(yellow) for wall and brown color for roof, after selection of color and part, old color should replace with new one.

How can we achieve this 
any suggestions or help

Comment: did you achieved this? i'm looking for the same. the below answer the changes the color but its not blending with the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708656/changing-color-space-on-and-image/10711552#10711552) of how you can change the specific colors of UIImage.

Two notes:

- the question is about gray to white color change, you can use this technique to change any color to any other,
- the code is taken from somewhere of the developers reference, so that colors in the snippet are kinda random.